# Phonegap Error : 401 Unauthorized - consuming Rest API with Basic Auth in Phonegap

Tags: php, rest, phonegap, codeigniter-restserver, codeigniter-restapi

I have create rest api in codeigniter and trying to consume it in phonegap app But its giving me Error - `401 Unauthorized` in Phonegap `index.html` page.

I am using Token Based Authentication in codeigniter. Rest api is working fine in postman and also its working fine when rest api consumed in Codeigniter View using same ajax code

**Codeigniter Rest Server Code I referenced -**

https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Below is Error I'm Receiving in Phonegap's `Index.html` -

Phonegap App URL (http://192.168.1.2:3000/)

[image]

[image]

**Below is Code I'm Using on Both Side in phonegap / Codeigniter View**
URL (http://localhost/webapi/welcome/index)

```
   <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script>
    var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost/webapi/api/user/",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "X-API-KEY": "7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b",
    "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNA==",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "552d3078-6d54-4d59-ba79-c94248b154b3"
  }
}
console.log("settings are -");
         console.log(settings);
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log("here api result come - ");
  console.log(response);
});
    </script>
```

**Screenshot of Rest API Working fine in Postman -** 
[image]

**Screenshot of COnsole When API Consumed in Codeigniter View using ajax -** 
[image]

Comment: Probably because you're firing the requests in postman from localhost, and the requests from phonegap go over the local network.

Comment: I tried again by closing postman but same error.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a CORS issue, since it doesn't straight up block the request. So my guess is that it's an issue within the PHP code

Comment: But when i tried in View of codeigniter (screenshot attached ) with same ajax code its returning output fine

Comment: @JesseSchokker The codeigniter view where i consume api is on the same project as that of api so they are on same url but phonegap app is on differerent url. does this info has any significance.

Comment: @JesseSchokker Update Details with cors error in console

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you won't be able to access  http://localhost/webapi/api/user/ from your emulator as your XAMPP server is hosted on a different machine (the emulator is a virtual machine). By changing the URL of your request to http://192.168.1.61/webapi/api/user/ for example, you can access the apache server hosted on your PC. You'll have to find out your local IP by opening a command prompt and typing ipconfig. You'll also need to ensure that your networks firewall allows incoming traffic from port 80.

Or you can try on cpanel or plesk server.

Comment: i think url in answer is wrong 'http://192.168.1.61' ? Changing API Url to http://192.168.1.2/webapi/api/user/ also didn't helped

Comment: Yes, this simple url. you can check ip on xampp

Comment: yes i tried placing my ip in place of localhost with / without port it didn't worked

Comment: Are you can try POST method.

Comment: I can try but my requirement is to get records. I think there is some problem in getting it throught ajax with basic auth. Because its working fine when i used same ajax code in  codeigniter view